# Split into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

In order to split cell into new columns, I use the following code:

```
   | Column1       | Column2
   | a;b;c;d;e;f   | 1;2;3;4

df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx')
new = df["Column1"].str.split(";", n=5, expand=True).
df['1st'] = new[0]
df['2nd'] = new[1]
df['3rd'] = new[2]
df['4th'] = new[3]
df['5th'] = new[4]
df['6th'] = new[5]
df.drop(columns=["Column1"], inplace=True)
```

The output will become

```
 Column:   1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 
             a   b   c   d   e   f;
```

What can I do in order to cancel the semicolon in the last item

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Can you show the actual code you're running to create the df as well as the split?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give a detailed explanation of your question so that others can understand it and answer it. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have made a typo in your question. I bet that there is a semicolon after the **f** when you read in the data and that it looks like this:

```
    Column1         Column2
0   a;b;c;d;e;f;    1;2;3;4
```

and *not* this:

```
    Column1         Column2
0   a;b;c;d;e;f     1;2;3;4
```

So, if you set `n=6` instead of `n=5`, then that should remove the final semicolon. Alternatively, you can just remove `n=6` as a parameter. Copy the first dataframe that I included in the answer above and run the below code with `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s+\s+')` below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard('\s+\s+')
new = df["Column1"].str.split(";", n=6, expand=True)
df['1st'] = new[0]
df['2nd'] = new[1]
df['3rd'] = new[2]
df['4th'] = new[3]
df['5th'] = new[4]
df['6th'] = new[5]
df.drop(columns=["Column1", "Column2"], inplace=True)
df
```